# Add direct link to company page in careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

When I search for a company on careers it gives me the jobs and the company page is listed on a separate tab.  This causes additional looking and clicking to get to their company page.  Is it possible to add the company page link (if it exists) directly in the company spotlight?  For instance:

[image]

In this case I knew they had a company page somewhere then I found myself looking directly on the page and completly missing the "1 company page" tab.  Finally I realized I overlooked that tab and it involved clicking the tab and then clicking the company page.  Either have the company page link right in the company spotlight or make it more noticeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The Featured Company ads now link directly to that company's company page.

---

Company Spotlights are being replaced by new ad units that will run both on Careers 2.0 and Stack Overflow.  Those new units will be coming out in a few weeks, and link to the Company Pages as you suggest.

Comment: I saw one on Stack Overflow today, you show it to random users at random times?

Comment: Right but those are just advertisements, I am talking specifically about directly in the careers page.  I understand and have seen the advertisements you mention but besides that I am looking for the actual company page right within the spotlight.

Comment: @JonH Yes.  The Company Spotlight is disappearing and being replaced by units similar to the ads you see being tested on SO right now.  The new version of Spotlights will link directly to the Company Page.

Comment: Okay that sounds good, you may want to add it to your answer for anyone else to see.